# Are free products of finite groups virtually free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the free product $A*B$ of two nontrivial finite groups always [virtually free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtually)? 
If yes, is it easy to show?

Comment: [Wikipedia claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtually#Virtually_free) yes, without proof or source.

Comment: My guess is that this follows from Bass-Serre theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass%E2%80%93Serre_theory) but I can't supply any details.

Comment: Take elements of the form $ab$ (with $a \in A\setminus\{1\}$ and $b \in B\setminsu \{1\}$.  These will tend to generate free subgroups, I think.

Comment: This follows very easily from the Kurosh subgroup theorem.  As t.b. notes, the kernel of the map from $A\ast B$ to $A\times B$ is a normal subgroup of finite index, and since the map is injective on both $A$ and $B$, the Kurosh subgroup theorem guarantees the kernel is free.

Comment: If you do not want to use the Kurosh subgroup theorem to prove Steve D's comment, you can induct on the number of commutators you are multiplying together (on $k$, where $[g_1, h_1]^{\epsilon_1}\ldots [g_k, h_k]^{\epsilon_k}$ where no commutator appears before its inverse). You want to show that (via induction) such a product will always have length $\geq k+3$ and will end with $g_kh_k$ if $\epsilon_k=1$ or $h_kg_k$ if $\epsilon_k=-1$. Can you see why this would prove the result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is a consequence of a theorem due to Nielsen. In fact, one can prove that for any two groups $A$ and $B$ (finite or not) the kernel $F$ of the canonical map $A \ast B \to A \times B$ (which is always a surjection) is freely generated by the set of commutators $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ with $a \in A \smallsetminus \{1\}$ and $b \in B \smallsetminus \{1\}$.

Given this, we see that if $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $F$ is a free group on $r = (|A|-1)(|B|-1)$ generators of index $[G:F] = |A| |B|$ in $G = A \ast B$.

*Note:* This confirms the formula using Euler characteristics given in Geoff's answer: $$\chi(A \ast B) = \frac{1}{|A|} + \frac{1}{|B|} - 1 = \frac{|A| + |B| - |A||B|}{|A||B|} = \frac{1-r}{[G:F]}$$

---

For a proof of Nielsen's theorem see e.g. Lyndon, *[Two notes on Rankin's book on the modular group](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700015433)*, Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society (1973), **16**, pp 454–457, Theorem 2. The proof is not terribly difficult, but it is not trivial.

For the convenience of the reader, here's Nielsen's paper *[A basis for subgroups of free groups](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1417)*, Math. Scand. **3** (1955), 33–45.

Alternatively, see Serre, *[Arbres, amalgames, $\operatorname{SL}_2$](http://books.google.ch/books?id=q9SAAAAAIAAJ)*, Proposition 4 in N<sup>o</sup> 1.1.3. (or [page 6](http://books.google.com/books?id=MOAqeoYlBMQC&pg=PA6) of the English translation).

Answer (score 3):

I think it can also be seen using the theory of Euler-Poincare characteristics as developed by C.T.C Wall, and explained in Serre's book "Trees." Excluding the case that either $A$ or $B$ is trivial, the key point to note is that $\chi(A*B) = \frac{1}{|A|} + \frac{1}{|B|}-1 \leq 0,$ while if $G = A*B,$ and $G$ has a free group $F$ on $r$ generators, then the general theory gives $\chi(G) = \frac{1-r}{[G:F]}.$ Once there 
is a free (not necessarily normal) subgroup of finite index, we are done, of course.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand the argument. I'm not sure what the precise general conditions are for $\chi(G) = \dfrac{1-r}{[G:F]}$ to hold, but doesn't this assume that you already know that there is a free subgroup of finite index?

Comment: Yes, I did not explain it very well. The argument is really that if the Euler characteristics of groups $A$ and $B$ and $C = A \cap B$ exist, then the Euler characteristic Euler characteristic of $A*_C B$ exists and is equal to $\chi(A) + \chi(B) - \chi(C).$ The existence of the Euler characeristic implicitly indicates the existence of the free subgroup of finite index. The Euler characteristic for a finite group $X$ is always defined, and is equal to $\frac{1}{|X|}.$ The Euler characteristic of a group $Y$ with a free subgroup $F$ on $t$ generators of finite index is $\frac{1-t}{[Y:F]}.$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Note that the Euler characteristic tells us that the free subgroup of index $|A|.|B|$ given in your answer is free on $(|A|-1)(|B|-1)$ generators.

Comment: Yes, this is left a bit implicit in my answer, but I thought it should be clear: I identified the generating set explicitly in terms of the set of commutators $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ with $a \in A \smallsetminus \{1\}$ and $B \smallsetminus \{1\}$ of which there are $(|A|-1)(|B|-1)$. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, it was clear enough I suppose . I was just really pointing out that the Euler characteristic method gives a direct calculation of the of the rank of the free group.

Answer (score 2):

A sketch of proof only based on algebraic topology:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite groups, $C_A$ and $C_B$ two complexes such that $\pi_1(C_A) \simeq A$ and $\pi_1(C_B) \simeq B$, $(\widehat{C_A},p_A)$ and $(\widehat{C_B},p_B)$ the universal covering of $C_A$ and $C_B$ respectively.

If one joins $C_A$ and $C_B$ by an edge $e$, then one constructs a complex $K$ satisfying $\pi_1(K) \simeq A \ast B$. Let $v_A$ and $v_B$ be the two end points of $e$ in $C_A$ and $C_B$ respectively. Let $r$ and $s$ the number of pre-images of $v_A$ and $v_B$ respectively in $\widehat{C_A}$ and $\widehat{C_B}$.

Let $C$ be the disjoint union of $s$ copies of $\widehat{A}$ and $r$ copies of $\widehat{B}$. Now, with respect to the natural projection $C \to K$, the points $v_A$ and $v_B$ have each one $rs$ pre-images. Then it is possible to construct a complex $\widehat{K}$ from the complex $C$ by joining each pre-image of $v_A$ by an edge to a pre-image of $v_B$, and conversely, in such a way that $\widehat{K}$ be connected.

Then $\widehat{K}$ is a finite covering of $K$ and $\pi_1(\widehat{K})$ is free, so the image of $\pi_1(\widehat{K})$ in $\pi_1(K) \simeq A \ast B$ is a finite-index free subgroup.

[In fact, the argument is closely related to Bass-Serre theory if we know graphs of spaces.]

Answer (score 2):

In fact, in his book (property 11 p. 120), Serre shows that the fundamental group of a finite graph of groups whose vertex groups are finite is virtually free. (The converse is also true, giving a characterization of virtually free groups.) I describe below the argument for the free product of two finite groups.

First, $A \ast B$ acts on a bipartite tree $T$ such that the edge stabilizers are trivial and the vertex stabilizers are conjugated to $A$ or $B$.

Let $|A|=n$, $|B|=m$ and $p=\max(n,m)$. Notice that $A$ (resp. $B$) acts freely on $A$ (resp. $B$) by multiplication on the left, hence a monomorphism $\varphi : A \hookrightarrow S_n \subset S_p$ (resp. $\phi : B \hookrightarrow S_m \subset S_p$). Now define $$ \psi = \varphi \ast \phi : A \ast B \to S_p,$$ and let $H= \mathrm{ker}(\psi)$. Clearly, $H$ is a finite-index subgroup of $A \ast B$. By construction, $H$ meets trivially $A$ and $B$; moreover, because $H$ is a normal subgroup, it meets trivially any conjugate of $A$ and $B$. Therefore, the action $H \curvearrowright T$, induced by $A \ast B \curvearrowright T$, is free.

We deduce that $H$ is a finite-index free subgroup of $A \ast B$; so $A \ast B$ is virtually free.

Comment: The proof in the comment of @user641 (and the answer of t.b.) are quite similar and give better lower bounds to the index of a finite rank free group, namely $nm$ as opposed to $\max(m,n)!$.