# Free group of finite rank: subgroup of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

This is a well-known result, but I can't find a proof of it without using topology.

> Let $m\geq2$ be an integer. Then the free group of rank $2$ contains a free group of rank $m$ as a finite-index subgroup.

Comment: It's not true. A finite index subgroup of the free group of rank $n$ has rank $k(n-1)+1$ for some positive integer $k$.

Comment: OK, I'll edit the question to $n=2$.

Comment: You could take the kernel of any epimorphism onto a cyclic group of order $m-1$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306116/the-free-group-f-2-contains-f-k.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Interesting, but I don't see anything about the index there.

Comment: @user147752 You realize Derek's comment above already answered your quest?

Comment: @DonAntonio Does it always exist?

Comment: Of course, @user147752. This follows at once from the universal property of free groups...or "directly": if the group is free on $\;\{x,y\}\;$ and $\;C_{m-1}=\langle c\rangle\;$ , just define $\;\phi(x):=c\;,\;\;\phi(y)=1\;$ and extend in the usual way to all normal (reduced) words.

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio, that was easy indeed. One more question: how do you see this kernel is a free group?

Comment: Socci: this is called  Schreier's theorem: subgroups of free groups are free.

Comment: @Socci, not only what studious mentions, but there's a very specific formula to calculate the rank of a (free) subgroup of finite index in a f.g. free group: it is $\;k(n-1)+1\;$ , where $\;k=$ the index and $\;n=$ the big group's rank. In the present example, we'd have $\;k=m-1\;,\;\;n=2\;$ and thus the kernel is free of rank $\;m\;$ ...

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments one can simply look at the kernel of epimorphisms to the finite cyclic group to find the groups. As an example $$f_n: F_2 \to C_n, x \mapsto \mathrm{generator},y \mapsto id$$ and note that $[F_2 : \ker f_n]=n$, and there is a well known formula $$[F_2:H]=\frac{\mathrm{rank}(H)-1}{\mathrm{rank}(F_2)-1},$$ which can be found in Combinatorial Group Theory, by Lyndon and Schupp (Prop 3.9 Chapter I) using "combinatorial methods" rather than topological. This implies for our case that $\mathrm{rank}(\ker f_n)=n+1$, so we get that there are finite index free subgroups of rank $\geq 2$.