# What is the difference between "a free group generated by A" and "a group generated by A"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups

What is the difference between "a free group generated by A" and "a group generated by A"?

I saw the definition, but I don't know. However, since $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is generated by two elements and is abelian, it is not a free group, so I understand that the two definitions are different.

Comment: A "free group" has no relations between the generators. A "group generated by $A$" could potentially have many relations between the generators.

Comment: Continuing Joshua P. Swanson's comment, in your example of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ you have already subdued your generators, say $a$ and $b$, to the the relation $ab=ba$, enforcing the commutativity. So $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is already a quotient of the free group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add a few examples. If $A=\{a\}$, then the free group generated by $A$ has the presentation $\langle a\rangle$ and is given by
$$
\langle a \rangle =\{a^k\mid k\in \Bbb Z\}\cong \Bbb Z,
$$
whereas the group generated by $A$ also can have a relation $a^n=1$ for some $n$, so that the group is given by
$$
\langle a \mid a^n=1\rangle \cong C_n,
$$
which is a finite cyclic group.

For $A=\{a,b\}$, the free group generated by $A$ is
$$
F_2=\langle a,b\rangle.
$$
This is an infinite, non-solvable group, which is quite different from
"the free abelian group"
$$
\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle \cong \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z.
$$
Examples of special properties of $F_2$ include the fact that  $F_2$ contains every free subgroup $F_k$ of rank $k\ge 2$.

[The free group $F_2$ contains $F_k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306116/the-free-group-f-2-contains-f-k)