# is $F_2$ a subgroup of any other $F_n$ for $n\geq 2$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, free-groups

This is more to check an argument
Since $F_2$ is a group generated by words of two generators, call them $\{a,b\}$
now every other $F_n$ (provided $n\geq 2$) will be all free words of more generators $\{a,b,c,d,...\}$ so it will surely contain words made up of only $a$ and $b$ and attaching one word with only letters $a$ and $b$ to another words containing $a$ and $b$ will still be a word containing only $a$ and $b$, this $F_2$ is closed under group multiplication.
Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yes! Although if you felt it necessary to check closure under multiplication, it's equally important to check the existence of inverses.

Comment: well if inverses exist in $\mathbb{F_2}$ assuming it is a group and all elements in of $\mathbb{F}_2$ exist in $\mathbb{F}_n$ then there are for sure already there (that was at least my thinking)

Comment: Yes that's obvious.   But what's surprising is that $F_2$ contains $F_n$ as a subgroup, $n\gt2. $ This isn't true for free abelian groups.

Comment: Incidentally, fairly famously $F_2$ also contains a subgroup isomorphic to $F_n$ for any $n.$

Comment: (We usually write $F_n$ for the free group on $n$ generators, and use $\mathbb F_n$ for the field with $n$ elements, if it exists.)

Comment: More interesting is the statement where $\mathbb F_n$ has an **isomorphic image** on  $\mathbb F_2$

Comment: @eggnog Really?! (I am stunned :D) $F_2$ contains (let's say ) $F_5$ as a subgroup. If I understood you correctly. But how is a word (for example of $F_5$) $aabcde$ containd in the set of all words of only the letters $(a,b)$?

Comment: It's rather counterintuitive.   But, if I'm not mistaken,  you can use the $a^kba^{-k}$ as a free basis.  Also btw, $F_2$ has an infinitely generated subgroup.

Comment: take a hike https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306116/the-free-group-f-2-contains-f-k well not too long hike :D