# The free group $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a subgroup of a free product

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, free-product

I am not so familiar with free groups so I want to study those groups. 
For example the free product is in general not a free group:
If we consider the free product $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2 $, then this product is isomorphic to $ D_{\infty}$.

My Question is: Is the free group $\mathbb{F}_2$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2$? If yes, how can you see this?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the generators of the three free factors are $a,b,c$ then the subgroup $\langle ab,bc\rangle$ is free of index $2$.

Comment: You can use the (details behind the proof of the) Kurosh subgroup theorem.

Comment: Even more is true: If $G=G_1 * G_2$ is a free product of nontrivial groups, then, unless $G_1\cong G_2\cong Z_2$, the group $G$ contains $F_2$.

Comment: A related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279385/when-is-g-ast-h-solvable

Comment: I should add to my comment that, if you are familiar with the Reidemeister-Schreier method for calculating subgroup presentations, then the proof that $\langle ab,bc \rangle$ is free is fairly trivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you write more about the Reidemeister-Schreier method ?  And is there a straightforward way to show that $<ab,bc>$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$ ? I have problems with the induction on the length of a reduced word (we only have to show injectivity)